# Android Kotlin filtering out items in list

Tags: android, arrays, json, list, kotlin

I have a list which contains sizes of clothing for that product.

`productfeed.variants.forEach { variants -> Log.d("TAG", "TESTING:: ${variants.option_values[0].name}")`

and has the output of

> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: SMALL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: MEDIUM
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: LARGE
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 1 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 2 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 3 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: SMALL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: MEDIUM
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: LARGE
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 1 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 2 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 3 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: SMALL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: MEDIUM
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: LARGE
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 1 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 2 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 3 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: SMALL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: MEDIUM
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: LARGE
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 1 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 2 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 3 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: SMALL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: MEDIUM
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: LARGE
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 1 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 2 XL
> 2020-11-10 21:24:06.862 19041-19041/com.example.fetchingjson D/TAG: TESTING:: 3 XL

This is showing all 30 variants

I wanted to know how I can get it to only show one set from SMALL to 3 XL

Comment: You want to show small, medium, L, 1 XL, 2XL, 3 XL in this way r8?

Comment: yes just one set of that not all 30 of them

Comment: can your write the output u want

Comment: the output i want is what you just commented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter extension of collections

```
val smallProducts = productfeed.variants.filter { 
    variant -> (logic to specify small products) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below `filter` extension for filter from the list.

```
var smallList = productfeed.variants.filter{
           v -> v.option_values[0].name.equal("SMALL")
        }
```

it will give you a list of SMALL.

Comment: please explain more what you want ?